# How to make a QIcon switch appearance without resetting it on the widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qicon

Now that dark mode has finally come to Windows with Qt 6.5, I noticed that a lot of my icons don't look too well on a dark background. So I'd like to use different icons for light and dark mode. And, to make things difficult, have the icons change (their appearance) when the user switches mode on his OS.

In order to avoid having to `setIcon()` on all kinds of widgets all over the place, I thought I'd subclass `QIcon` and have it change its pixmap on the `colorSchemeChanged` signal.

```
class ThemeAwareIcon(QIcon):
    def __init__(self, dark_pixmap, light_pixmap, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.dark_pm = dark_pixmap
        self.light_pm = light_pixmap
        self.app = QApplication.instance()
        self.app.styleHints().colorSchemeChanged.connect(self.set_appropriate_pixmap)
        self.set_appropriate_pixmap()

    def set_appropriate_pixmap(self):
        current_scheme = self.app.styleHints().colorScheme()
        pm = self.dark_pm if current_scheme == Qt.ColorScheme.Dark else self.light_pm
        self.addPixmap(pm, QIcon.Mode.Normal, QIcon.State.On)
```

This works almost as intended; pixmaps are changed upon the signal. It's just that the changed pixmap isn't displayed on the widget that the icon is set on. The only way I found to make the change visible is to reset the icon on the widget, and that is what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

So, can my icon class be rescued somehow or is what I want just not possible this way?

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that QIcon is not an actual resource, but more like an abstract reference. I don't use Qt6 yet, but I can suggest some tests: 1. try to do `widget.style().unpolish(widget)` on the target widget (and, eventually, `widget.style().polish(widget)`; 2. try to temporarily change the QApplication style and then set the original one: Qt always provides at least the `windows` and `fusion` styles, so you could just get the *current* style `objectName()`, change it to any of the above (but different than the current one, by checking with case insensitive), and revert it again;

Comment: 3. if you're using stylesheets, try with `app.setStyleSheet(app.styleSheet())` (if you're using an application wide QSS) or `widget.setStyleSheet(widget.styleSheet())` (if you're using a style sheet specifically set **to** the widget). If none of the above works, the only solution I can think of is to create your own QIconEngine subclass and always use that (with carefully written caching, possibly class based); to easy things up, create a helper function/class that automatically creates a QIcon with the new engine using similar functions for their creation.

Comment: 1. (un)polishing requires access to the widget, and you might just as well reset the icon then. This whole exercise was an attempt to do this without accessing the widget. 2. Changing styles has no influence.  In the mean time I found a dirty little trick: You can pass the widget to the constructor of the icon. Now the icon knows which widget it's in and it can reset itself after the pixmap change. Another option is to do some refactoring and centralise all the icon handling. I think creating my own icon engine is too far beyond my current skill set. I have no idea how to approach that.

Comment: I also have a feeling that the widget gets the necessary pixmaps form the icon when the icon is set and never touches the icon again after that - updating or repainting the widget is also ineffective -. I don't think creating a special icon engine could solve anything if that assumption is true.

Comment: I suggested the polishing *as a test* to see if it works, not as a solution. And you don't need to create a QIconEngine from scratch, just subclass it and override the required functions (probably `pixmap()` or `paint()` will suffice). The point is that it's the icon engine that normally draws the pixmap (widgets normally call the `icon.pixmap()`), and adding a pixmap *after* it's been set doesn't change the currently used pixmap (and it could be even completely ignored by the engine).

Comment: With creating a new engine I also meant subclassing. I still have no idea what a custom engine would have to do different than the default one. I also have no clue how the widget and the icon interact. When I override the icon's `paint()` and `pixmap()` with just a print() and super(), I see no prints.

Comment: That's because, as said above, QIcon is an abstract object, and subclassing it is pointless, because as soon as you use `setIcon()` the subclass will be useless. If you do `setIcon()` with your `ThemeAwareIcon` subclass and you try to get back the `icon()` from the same widget, you will *not* get your `ThemeAwareIcon` instance back. The *only* way to override the behavior of QIcons is by creating a custom QIconEngine, so, if you cannot do it, the only remaining alternative is to do what explained in the linked post for which yours was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that you don't you don't get the same Icon back as you put in. I just thought that it returned a copy with the same pixmaps and that the original icon was still being used inside. But it looks like I'll have to dig into IconEngines, altough documentation and examples seem sparse.

Comment: Never underestimate the powers of a good night of sleep. This whole IconEngine thing is actually pretty simple. The docs just make it seem needlessly complicated. All it has to do is return pixmaps. And then you can make it fancy with memoisation for sizes and modes etc. Now if this question would be reopened I could probably post a decent answer (in a couple of days).

Comment: Told you so :-) Yes, I agree, the QIcon and QIconEngine documentation is a bit hermetic (probably because 99.9% of the times the existing implementation is sufficient for any developer and by the time you reach that 0.01% you're probably experienced enough to understand it on your own). My suggestion is to create the subclass with two *class* attributes: a dictionary with file names as keys and actual QIcons for the "current" theme, and a "controller" QObject that will eventually clear the dictionary; when the *first* instance is created check if the controller exists and if it doesn't then ->

Comment: -> create it by ensuring that you make it a class member (eg. `self.__class__.controller` ). The controller is a basic QObject subclass that is connected to the `colorSchemeChanged` signal and clears the class dictionary. What remains is to simply override `pixmap()` of the engine, check if the name exists, if it doesn't create the QIcon with the path to the current theme, and finally return the icon's `pixmap()` with the function arguments. Remember that each QIcon has its own IconEngine instance, so you'll probably want a helper function or pseudo QIcon subclass that recreates it.

Comment: Finally, I don't use Qt6 yet, so I don't know if that `colorSchemeChanged` also repolishes the whole app (and icons). If it doesn't, icons will probably not be updated until a repaint is required (especially for item views if you're using QIcons for items), so you could try to re-set the current application style, which is normally enough: if you're not using a custom style, you can do `QApplication.setStyle(QApplication.style().objectName()), or even try with `app.setStyleSheet(app.styleSheet())` *if* you're using application wide style sheets. I reopened the question, good luck! :-)

Comment: Could you add a 'qiconengine' tag to this question? You have enough points to add new tags.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of a struggle, I found out how to use `QIconEngine` to get the icons to switch on their own.

> Here's a bit a background info for people who (like I did) struggle
> with the concept of `QIcon`, `QIconEngine`, and the widgets they're
> set upon. This explanation may not be 100% accurate, but 100% accuracy
> has the tendancy to be 0% understandable for beginners.
>
> A `QIcon` is an interface for a `QIconEngine`. You can add image
> files, retrieve pixmaps etc. through the `QIcon`, but as soon as the
> icon is set on a widget, the QIcon object becomes useless. **The widget
> only interacts with the engine, not with QIcon**. So if you want to
> customise the behaviour of an icon when it's set on a widget you have
> to do it in the engine.   In most cases the widget will retrieve the
> icons from the engine by calling `pixmap()` with the desired size,
> mode, and state, but rumour has it that widgets can also call
> `paint()`

Here is a very basic general purpose implementation. Any signal can be used to trigger the switch.

In case of switching at colorscheme change, there's no need to pass the signal to the engine cause it's globally available.

This example 'offloads' the pixmap generation to regular `QIcons`. This may not be the most efficient way but you'll get default behaviour in all circumstances.

```
class SwitchingEngine(QIconEngine):
    offload = {}

    def __init__(self, file_name, f1, f2, sig):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_name = file_name
        if self.file_name not in self.offload:
            self.offload[self.file_name] = {
                True: QIcon(f1),
                False: QIcon(f2),
            }
        self.switch = True
        sig.connect(lambda: setattr(self, 'switch', not self.switch))

    def pixmap(self, size: QSize, mode: QIcon.Mode, state: QIcon.State):
        return self.offload[self.file_name][self.switch].pixmap(size, mode, state)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, rect: QRect, mode: QIcon.Mode, state: QIcon.State):
        return self.offload[self.file_name][self.switch].paint(painter, rect, mode, state)

    
class SwitchingIcon(QIcon):
    def __init__(self, file_name, sig):
        f1 = f'switch1/{file_name}'
        f2 = f'switch2/{file_name}'
        engine = SwitchingEngine(file_name, f1, f2, sig)
        super().__init__(engine)
```

and as a bonus a little 'bring your own icon files' test app.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QToolButton, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QStyleFactory
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QIconEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sw = QPushButton('switch')
        dis = QPushButton('disable')

        but1 = QToolButton()
        but2 = QToolButton()
        but3 = QToolButton()

        icon1 = SwitchingIcon('fn1', sw.clicked)
        icon2 = SwitchingIcon('fn2', sw.clicked)
        icon3 = SwitchingIcon('fn3', sw.clicked)

        but1.setIcon(icon1)
        but2.setIcon(icon2)
        but3.setIcon(icon3)

        sw.clicked.connect(self.update)
        dis.clicked.connect(lambda: but1.setEnabled(not but1.isEnabled()))
        dis.clicked.connect(lambda: but2.setEnabled(not but2.isEnabled()))
        dis.clicked.connect(lambda: but3.setEnabled(not but3.isEnabled()))

        cmb = QComboBox()
        cmb.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        cmb.currentTextChanged.connect(QApplication.instance().setStyle)

        tbs = QHBoxLayout()
        tbs.addWidget(but1)
        tbs.addWidget(but2)
        tbs.addWidget(but3)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(cmb)
        lay.addLayout(tbs)
        lay.addWidget(sw)
        lay.addWidget(dis)

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: This is a good start, but it has some important issues: for instance, you're creating a connection for **every** created icon, which may be fine for a small case scenario, but if widgets are dynamically created and could contain *lots* of those icons, the result will be that the connected function will be called for *every* instance, which is not very effective. That could also be a problem for icons that are being destroyed when the objects that use them are, since the lambda creates a closure and the instance would become persistent, possibly resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: Yeah, yeah. This is not a perfect implementation. More a 'proof of concept' that I, and maybe others, can build upon.

Comment: I know that, but it's important to highlight those aspects *especially* for others. Remember that, while lambdas are extremely useful and powerful, they are not without drawbacks (and closures are some of them). You can do the same in a more consistent way by using a method instead of a lambda: just add something like `def toggle(self): self.switch = not self.switch`, and directly connect the signal to the instance method. Still, what written above about connecting *every* instance **must** be considered. Since this is done for a "global" purpose, it makes no sense to make unique connections.

Comment: Also note (I'm annoying, I know :-P ) that your description about QIconEngine is imprecise. While it's true that it *usually* **does** return QPixmaps, it's not limited to that: it's true that `pixmap()` is the function that is *normally* called when drawing icons, but the documentation also specifies that, by default, it *relies* on the `paint` function, and some styles (especially DPI aware ones) may choose to use `paint()` instead, so you should at least override that too.

Comment: You're the good kind of annoying. Yes, the docs say that `paint()` is used internally by the engine, I can't find any reference that widgets also may call it, but I'll take your word for it.